# How to disable auto-capitalization of an EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

This will have a really simple answer, but I can't seem to find what it is. I want to disable the auto-capitalization of an EditText so that, by default, the first letter entered with not be automatically capitalized. I still want to allow capitalization, but only if the user manually does so.

I've tried `android:capitalize="none"` on my EditText, and I've tried `android:inputType="text"` but both still auto-capitalize the first letter. I don't want to use a `TextWatcher` because on the soft keyboard it will still show the shift key as pressed for the first letter, and I'm nit-picky and don't want that to show.

Comment: Does the auto-capitalization occurred by your current keyboard software?
If it's true, disable your keyboard's auto-cap setting.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could try using `android:inputType="none"` instead.

**UPDATE:**

You could also try using `android:inputType="text|textEmailAddress"`

Comment: Still auto-capitalizes. I would suspect specifying "none" would just use whatever default settings the user has on his phone.

Comment: Accepted answer should probably be changed to android:inputType="textFilter" (below.)  I think something has changed recently because that was the only answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `android:inputType="textFilter"`? That will disable all text filters, so there's no auto-correcting.

Comment: That's really weird, it doesn't auto-capitalize for me. Are you using just a regular EditText or did you modify it?

Comment: @Brian I have implemented EditText class to support custom type face file. Now its auto capitalizing every letter. I am ot able to fix it. Any suggestion.??

Comment: I suspect something has changed recently.  I tried type = none and type = text and text|textEmailAddress and none worked.  android:inputType="textFilter"? did wortk however.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, I think what you're (or more accurately, whoever finds this in the future) looking for is this table of all the options that can be used for the inputType:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType

In this specific case, I would recommend "text".
`Just plain old text. Corresponds to TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL.`