# How to prevent capitalization without preventing line breaks in EditText

Tags: android

I have an edit text box. I don't want the first letter in the input to be auto capitalized. I tried

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

However, I need to be able to use line breaks when I pressed the return key and now I am no longer able to do that.

How can I prevent capitalization without removing line break functionality from return key?

I've tried these two to no avail

```
android:inputType="none" 
android:inputType="text|textEmailAddress"
```

Comment: try this android:inputType="none"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable auto-capitalization of an EditText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976950/how-to-disable-auto-capitalization-of-an-edittext)