# EditText remove capitalization of the first letter in android

Tags: android, kotlin, input, capitalization

code:

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/etDownloadGame"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:digits="123456790qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm_-"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter game name"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="textFilter"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

as I asked in the title of the post, I'm having trouble with removal of the auto capitalization of the first letter in that EditText field in an app I've been building (I've already looked through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976950/how-to-disable-auto-capitalization-of-an-edittext), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976950/how-to-disable-auto-capitalization-of-an-edittext), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808705/first-letter-capitalization-for-edittext), but none of them resolved my problem)

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine multiple input types with `|`. In this case you want to add `text` for text with no capitalization specified.

`android:inputType="text|textFilter"`

The types are listed [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:inputType).